# Rewriting parts of a string inside an index

Tags: python, matrix-indexing

having a little bit of trouble indexing parts of a list in **Python 3**. The prompt/question is below and I have already made the input text file.

Prompt:
You are given a file called class_scores.txt, where each line of the file contains a oneword
username and a test score separated by spaces, like below:

```
GWashington 83
JAdams 86
```

Write code that scans through the file, adds 5 points to each test score, and outputs the usernames
and new test scores to a new file, scores2.txt.

Here is the code I've written so far:

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in open('class_scores.txt')]
scores = [line.split(' ') for line in lines]
newScores = open('class_newScores.txt', 'w')
```

The trouble is, when I try to write new values to the scores, the index is the whole line of the word instead of the score so I can't change it.

Eg the index will output:
GWashington 83

Instead of:
83

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scores = [line.split(' ') for line in lines]
```

will return you an array

> ['GWashington', '83']

What you want is

```
scores = [int(line.split(' ')[1]) for line in lines]
```

which returns

> 83

so that you can do arithmetic manipulations